# Python Script Hanging on Try/Except Clauses

Tags: python, exception, try-catch

I'm trying to extract data from an html page using Beautiful Soup.  Some of the html is malformed or doesn't even exist, and I need to use regex to try to inspect it in this case.  I handle this using try/except clauses.  Here's my script:

```
def get_metadata(path):
    path = path.replace('\\', '\\')
    rx_1 = r'Supersedes:?\s*[^\r\n]*[\r\n]+(.*?)[ \r\n]+(?:Service)?\s*Serial Numbers?:?[ \r\n]+.*?[ \n\r]+\*+[\n\r]+\*[\n\r]*([A-Za-z ]+)[ \n\r]\*+[\n\r]+\*+[ \n\r]*\*+[\n\r]+\*+[ \n\r]*(?:\*[ \n\r]*)+(?:Author[:\w\/]+ ([\.\w\/\sï¿½]+))'
    rx_2 = r'(.*)(?:Service)[\r\n ]+Serial Numbers?:?[ \r\n]+.*?[ \n\r]+\*+[\n\r]+\*[\n\r]*([A-Za-z ]+)[ \n\r]\*+[\n\r]+\*+[ \n\r]*\*+[\n\r]+\*+[ \n\r]*(?:\*[ \n\r]*)+(?:Author[:\w\/]+ ([\.\w\/\sï¿½]+))'
    rxs = [rx_1, rx_2]
    data = {}

    try:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(open(path, 'rb'), 'html.parser')
        pre = soup.find('pre')
        if pre:
            pre_string = pre.text
        else:
            pre_string = soup.text

        attachments = []
        data['path'] = path
        try:
            description = soup.find(text=re.compile(r'\s*Title:?')).find_next('td').contents[0]
            description = description.strip().replace('\n', '\\n').replace(',', '\\n')
            data['document_description'] = description
        except Exception as why:
        # SOUP COULDN'T FIND IT, MUST RESORT TO REGEX
            for rx in rxs:
                try:
                    match = re.search(rx, pre_string, re.S|re.M)
                    if match:
                        description = match[1]
                        if not description:
                            continue
                        else:
                            if description == 'Service':
                                continue
                            description = re.sub(before_d, '', description)
                            description = re.sub(after_d, '', description)
                            description = re.sub('([\r\n]|\s+)', ' ', description)
                            data['document_description'] = description
                            break
                    else:
                        continue
                except Exception as why:
                    err = {'path': path, 'error': str(why), 'field': 'description'}
#                    record_err(err)
                    data['document_description'] = None
                    continue
            if not data['document_description']:
                data['document_description'] = None
                pass
        html = soup.prettify('utf-8')

        with open(path, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(html)
            update_log(log)

#        with open(path, 'wb') as f:
 #           f.write(html)
  #          update_log(log)

    except Exception as why:
        print('failed to open soup' + str(why))
        pass
    return data
```

Something is going wrong so that instead of raising an exception when a line like the following can't be evaluated

```
  try:
        description = soup.find(text=re.compile(r'\s*Title:?')).find_next('td').contents[0]
```

the script just freezes during execution.

I run `get_metadata` for several different paths, and this works until this problem with the exception handling happens.  Each time a path is tried it is logged.  When a file with exceptions is read, it freezes on this file and I must keyboard escape.  The strange this is that the error seems to be not handled as if it were in a try clause:

```
 python just-meta.py
SNViewer-HTML\Compliance\CE\SN_CE_Compliance_01.htm
SNViewer-HTML\Compliance\CE\SN_CE_Compliance_02.htm
SNViewer-HTML\Compliance\CE\SN_CE_Compliance_03.htm
SNViewer-HTML\Compliance\CE\SN_CE_Compliance_04.htm
SNViewer-HTML\Compliance\CE\SN_CE_Compliance_05.htm
SNViewer-HTML\Compliance\CE\SN_CE_Compliance_06.htm
SNViewer-HTML\Compliance\CS\SN_CS_Compliance_01A.htm
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "just-meta.py", line 109, in get_metadata
    description = soup.find(text=re.compile(r'\s*Title:?')).find_next('td').contents[0]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_next'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "just-meta.py", line 353, in <module>
    migrate()
  File "just-meta.py", line 46, in migrate
    metadata = get_metadata(f)
  File "just-meta.py", line 115, in get_metadata
    match = re.search(rx, pre_string, re.S|re.M)
  File "C:\Users\Joseph\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\re.py", line 182, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
```

Can anyone give me any advice on how to solve this?

Comment: `soup.find(text=re.compile(r'\s*Title:?'))` became `None` (nothing found). You have to handle that special case.

Comment: @KlausD.  I thought I did handle it?  Isn't that what it being inside the try/except block does?

Comment: Catching all exceptions makes debugging rather difficult. You should only handle those exceptions you are interested in and let the rest bubble up. Stack trace will usually point you in the right direction.